# Finding envelope of family of curves with two parameters

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, envelope

[image]Consider this $x/a+y/b=1$, where the parameters $a,b$ are related by $a^2+b^2=c$, where $c$ is a constant. Here they consider  $a,b$ as a function of some other parameter $t$ and proceed to differentiate with respect to $t$? Why is it so? Why should they be a function of $t$
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more detail ? What exactly is differentiated, what is the result, and who is "they" ?

Comment: Those two equations can be differentiated with respect to $t$ and then eliminating $a,b$ gives the envelope. My question is why are $a,b$ a function of $t$?

Comment: You have not provided details of the context, and so we cannot mind-read and answer your "why" questions. But if $a=a(t)$ and $b=b(t)$ are functions of a single parameter $t$, this fits the classical set-up for an envelope of curves in the plane. A two-parameter family of curves won't necessarily have an envelope.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. The context is finding the equation of the envelope for the given straight line.

Comment: The family of straight lines. A one-parameter family will (subject to some basic conditions) have an envelope. A two-parameter family will not. With the two parameters, you're basically considering all lines in the plane with the exception of lines through the origin and horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: In one text they consider $a,b$ as functions of $t$ then differentiate the two equations and by eliminating $a,b$ they obtain $x^(2/3)+y^(2/3)=c^(2/3)$ as the envelope.

Comment: You need to typeset that as x^{2/3}, etc. The envelope will depend on which specific  functions of $t$ we use. You ca find various posts on this site discussing how to find envelopes and why it works; I know because I've written several such answers.

Comment: I’ll try to add the picture in the main question. Nothing is mentioned about which function of $t$.

Comment: Where are you seeing $t$? They are using the constraint $a^2b^3=c^5$, with $c$ presumably a fixed constant to then treat $a$ as the parameter. This is not putting in random functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, but rather using $a=t$ and $b=(c^5/t^2)^{1/3}$, if you insist on writing it that way. ... And this has nothing to do with the equation you wrote down earlier with $2/3$ powers. That envelope is a classic example that comes from a family of ellipses.

Comment: @TedShifrin now I’ve added the picture of the text that considers $t$